# I am having problem with communication between siblings components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

The problem is the following I have this structure:

[image: structure]

Where the component 'FormNotas' is a form that I send information to an API in the backend, and the 'TabelaNotas' component displays what comes from the database. The problem here is that I can not update the 'TabelaNotas' component when I enter a record through the 'FormNotas' component.

Follow the codes below:

**Notas.js**

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import TabelaNotas from './TabelaNotas'
import {Button, Card, Icon} from 'antd'
import FormNotas from './FormNotas'

export default () => {

    const [exibirForm , setExibirForm] = useState({ exibirForm : false});

    function showForm(){
        setExibirForm({exibirForm : true})
    }

    function closeForm(){
        setExibirForm({exibirForm : false})
    }

    return (
        <>
             <div style={Styled.alinhamentoButton}>
                <Button type="primary" icon="plus" onClick={()=> showForm()}>Lançar Nota</Button>
            </div>
            {exibirForm.exibirForm === true ? 
            (
                <Card style={Styled.card}> 
                     <h4 style={Styled.h4}><Icon type="deployment-unit" /> Lançamento de nota</h4>
                    <Button type="dashed" style={Styled.buttonClose} onClick={()=> closeForm()}><Icon type="close" /></Button>
                    <FormNotas />
                </Card>
            ) : (<></>)}
            <TabelaNotas />
        </>
    )
}

const Styled = {
    buttonClose : {
        float: 'right',
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        transform: 'translateX(-50%) translateY(50%)'
    },
    alinhamentoButton : {
        display: 'flex', 
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        marginBottom: '10px',
    },
    card : {
        marginBottom: 25,
        display: 'flex', 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out 0s'
    },
    h4 : { 
        letterSpacing: '-0.5px',
        wordSpacing:'-4.5px',
    },
}
```

**TabelaNotas.js**

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useReducer} from 'react'
import {API} from '../../Services/API/API'
import {Headers} from '../../Services/API/Headers'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Table, Card, Button } from 'antd'
import columns from './columnsTableNotas'


export default () => {
    const [ notas , setNotas] = useState({ data: [] , loading: true}, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(API.urlBase , { query: ` {getNotaByUser(id: 1){ id Nota Referencia Tipo_nota Data_criacao materia_id{ Nome_Materia Professor Ano_letivo Data_criacao }}}` }, Headers)
        .then( resp => {
            setNotas({ data : resp.data.data.getNotaByUser, loading: false})
        })
    } , []);
    
    return (
        <Card>
            <Table dataSource={notas.data} columns={columns} loading={notas.loading} rowKey={record => record.id} />
        </Card>
    )
}
```

**FormNotas.js**

```js
import React, {useEffect , useState } from 'react'
import {Form, Select, Input, Button, message} from 'antd'
import {API} from '../../Services/API/API'
import {Headers} from '../../Services/API/Headers'
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {

    const [dados, setDados] = useState({ materias : [] , loading: true , cbxMateria : '', txtNota: null, cbxReferencia: '1' , cbxTipo: 'Prova'}) 

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post(API.urlBase, { query: `{getMateriaByUser(id : ${API.userBase}){id Nome_Materia Professor Ano_letivo Data_criacao  user_id{ id }}}` }, Headers)
        .then( resp => {
            setDados({ ...dados, materias: resp.data.data.getMateriaByUser, loading: false})
        })
    }, []);

    function salvarFormulario(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post(API.urlBase, { query: `mutation { newNota(input: {Nota: ${dados.txtNota}, Referencia: "${dados.cbxReferencia}", Tipo_nota: "${dados.cbxTipo}", materia_id : ${dados.cbxMateria}, user_id: ${API.userBase}}) {id Nota Referencia Tipo_nota Data_criacao}}`}, Headers)
        .then( resp => {
            message.success('Materia inserida com sucesso!')
            setDados({...dados, cbxMateria : '', txtNota: null, cbxReferencia: '1' , cbxTipo: 'Prova'})
        })
    }

    function AtualizarInput(e){
        setDados({...dados, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
    }

    function AtualizarSelect(nome , e){
       setDados({...dados, [nome] : e})
    }

    return (
            
            <Form layout="inline" method="post" onSubmit={ e => salvarFormulario(e)}>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Select name="cbxMateria" onSelect={(e) => AtualizarSelect("cbxMateria" , e)} placeholder="Disciplina" style={styled.select} loading={dados.loading} defaultActiveFirstOption={true}>
                        {dados.materias.map( (res , i ) => {
                            return (
                                <Select.Option key={i} value={res.id}>{res.Nome_Materia}</Select.Option>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Input type="text" name="txtNota" placeholder="Nota" required  style={styled.input} value={dados.txtNota} onChange={AtualizarInput}/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Select defaultValue='1' name="cbxReferencia" style={styled.select} value={dados.cbxReferencia} onSelect={(e) => AtualizarSelect("cbxReferencia" , e)}>
                            <Select.Option value="1">1º Referência</Select.Option>
                            <Select.Option value="2">2º Referência</Select.Option>
                            <Select.Option value="3">3º Referência</Select.Option>
                            <Select.Option value="4">4º Referência</Select.Option>
                    </Select>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Select defaultValue='Prova' name="cbxTipo" style={styled.select} value={dados.cbxTipo} onSelect={(e) => AtualizarSelect("cbxTipo" , e)}>
                            <Select.Option value="Prova">Prova</Select.Option>
                            <Select.Option value="Trabalho">Trabalho</Select.Option>
                            <Select.Option value="Nota Extra">Nota Extra</Select.Option>
                    </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" name="Send" icon="plus">Salvar registro</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
            </Form>
    )
}

const styled = {
    input:{ 
        width: 150
    },
    select : {
        width: 150
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the notas collection and the function for sending data to the API to a common parent component and pass them down as props to each (the function to FormNotas and the collection to TableNotas). This coverts both FormNotas and TableNotas into presentational components that delegate their logic to a container component that can control both.

For more on container and presensentional components, [read this](https://medium.com/@yassimortensen/container-vs-presentational-components-in-react-8eea956e1cea).